# Disable drag and drop for certain cellViews in ListView xamarin android?

Tags: listview, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I implemented Drag and drop for xamarin listview with reference to below link

https://github.com/pnavk/Drag-and-Drop-ListView

But i require to disable drag and drop for few items of listView based on certain criteria. Help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> But i require to disable drag and drop for few items of listView based on certain criteria. Help is appreciated.

You can do it in `DraggableListView.cs`'s `OnLongPress` event. In `OnLongPress` event, the position and of the long pressed item is already retrieved, so what you need to do is just retrieve the long pressed item add an if-statement according to your "certain criteria":

```
public void OnLongPress (MotionEvent e)
{
        mTotalOffset = 0;

        int position = PointToPosition (mDownX, mDownY);

        if (position < 0 || !LongClickable)
            return;

        //added codes
        var item=Adapter.GetItem(position);
        //if the user long pressed a Vegetables, then it can't be drag and drop
        if (item != null && item.ToString() == "Vegetables")
        {
            return;
        }

        int itemNum = position - FirstVisiblePosition;

        ...
}
```